# How to change iPhone's Screen Display Color with Private APIs?

Tags: ios, iphone, colors, iphone-privateapi, backlight

I have seen so many posts regarding the same but all are outdated or not working anymore.

I am using iOS-Runtime-Headers and everything is just nicely setup. But it said that I can't find out the method in which I can set iPhone's screen display color. This should be possible with private APIs as long as, we've NightMode from iOS 9.3.1.

And yes, I am aware that if I will be using any private APIs, Apple will surely reject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check out the [GammaThingy](https://github.com/thomasfinch/GammaThingy) project out?

It works a bit similar to f.lux and NightShift and maybe the code of the [GammaController](https://github.com/thomasfinch/GammaThingy/blob/master/GammaTest/mvc/controller/GammaController.m) there can help you achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out [GoodNight](https://github.com/anthonya1999/GoodNight), which is based off of GammaThingy, but a little bit more "polished". The reason why you cannot find the methods in the dumped headers is because the entire app uses C functions, NOT Objective-C methods. Specifically, it uses the private IOMobileFramebuffer framework (IOMobileFramebufferSetGammaTable is the main function used). I have put together a rather extensive disassembly of it [here](https://gist.github.com/anthonya1999/e0bffcac15b6b208126d) if you are interested.